# How to override __new__ metaclass method of a model in Django

Tags: python, django

I am using `Django 1.6` and `model inheritance` in Django. What I wanna do is, hooking new class extending.

It would be done in Python like,

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, newattrs):
        do_what_you_want_before()
        result= super(Meta, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, newattrs)
        do_what_you_want_after()
        return result

class Foo:
    __metaclass__ = Meta

class SubFoo(Foo):
    pass
```

When this part of code is initialized, custom `__new__` method will be invoked.

How can I do that in Django with model inheritance. When you try to do this with Django Models, an error such that, is given:

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of inheriting from `type`, inherit from `django.db.models.base.ModelBase` ([source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L60)).

Comment: Works in django 2.2 too. Just the signature is different: def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs, **kwargs):